# Spark SQL Insert Select with a column list?

Tags: apache-spark

As I read Spark/Hive SQL documentation is appears that **Insert** into table with a **Column List** is not supported in Spark 2.4 and earlier versions.

I have a source table and a destination table with different number of columns and different column names which I need to copy.

Does this mean I have to code this in PySpark to do this job as Spark SQL will not be able to do it ??

Example:

```
input_table( cola, colb, colc, cold, cole)

output_table(fieldx, fieldy, fieldz)
```

In SQL (assuming RDBMS such as MS-SQL, PostgreSQL etc) I would do the following:

```
insert into output_table(fieldx, fieldy, fieldz) select cola, colb, colc from input_table
```

Spark SQL does not allow this, it does not accept a column list in Insert SQL statement.

**Question**: how can I do this task with minimum of code and maximum performance in either PySpark or (ideally) in Spark-SQL (I am using Spark 2.4) ?

thank you

Comment: Is this something that is updated in a later version of Spark (> 2.4) where you can specify columns?  Not supporting this basic sql syntax seems pretty poor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the columns in `output` that won't be copied from `input_table` as `null` in `select`. (This is what would happen when only a set of columns, not all, would be `insert`ed with a column list, if it were allowed)

```
insert into output_table
select cola, colb, colc,null as other1,--..specify non-copied column values as null 
from input_table
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I started to do, will this perform optimally? I need to use some SQL functions/expressions on some of the select columns to transform them such as to uppercase some values, to extract some sub-strings, cast other columns, etc. The data source is huge, many billions of rows.....